# How can I get sticky div inside another div using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap 4 and was wondering if it's possible to stick a div to the bottom of its parent div. I use class `.container` with class `.row` and some child divs:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <h3>Title</h3>               
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <h4>Line I want to be fixed to bottom</h4>
        </div>
        <div>...</div>  <!--Similar div--> 
        <div>...</div>  <!--Similar div--> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

So every div in the `.row` get the height of the highest div and for others there is a space left.
Now I have something like that:

```
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
|-------title------||-------title------||-------title------|
|-------text1------||-------text2------||-------text3------|
|-------text1------||-------text2------||--lineIWantToFix--|
|-------text1------||--lineIWantToFix--||-------space------|
|-------text1------||-------space------||-------space------|
|--lineIWantToFix--||-------space------||-------space------|
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
```

And I want it to be like that:

```
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
|-------title------||-------title------||-------title------|
|-------text1------||-------text2------||-------text3------|
|-------text1------||-------text2------||-------space------|
|-------text1------||-------space------||-------space------|
|-------text1------||-------space------||-------space------|
|--lineIWantToFix--||--lineIWantToFix--||--lineIWantToFix--|
+------------------++------------------++------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use flex.

It's much cleaner, safer (no overlaps), scalable (it can be multirow) and it works fine on mobile too.

Here is my solution: https://codepen.io/zalog/pen/qPWZJE

No fancy CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.row > div > * { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Html:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 d-flex flex-column">
      <h3>title</h3>
      <p>text</p>
      <h4 class="mt-auto">bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

You may have a dynamic height on your text or bottom line, and will never overlap.
But, you must prepare all your parents to have 100% height for our flex to work.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Wow, that's even better solution. Thank you!

Comment: Great!
You can also check this awesome [guide about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can used `flexbox` functionally in Bootstrap-4 and set `position: absolute` to set sticky element.

```css
.main-col {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.main-col h4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row d-flex">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 main-col">
            <h3>Title</h3>               
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <h4>Line I want to be fixed to bottom</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 main-col">
            <h3>Title</h3>               
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <h4>Line I want to be fixed to bottom</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 main-col">
            <h3>Title</h3>               
            <p style="text-align: justify">Text</p>
            <h4>Line I want to be fixed to bottom</h4>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to help you :)